# Error google API: "Credentials in post body and basic Authorization header do not match"

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I've implemented a python script that connect to google drive and download my files. For the authorization, I've followed the quickstart guide and code sample on google site.

The problem is this: when I give my authorization for the first time, a token.pickle is generated, but after time (not much, maybe less than 1 hour) i receive this error:

> google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_request: Credentials in post body and basic Authorization header do not match', '{\n  "error": "invalid_request",\n  "error_description": "Credentials in post body and basic Authorization header do not match"\n}')

If I delete the token.pickle and do the authorization again from browser all works again, but obviously I need a token valid for a longer time.

The code for authorization is this:

```py
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """

    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

This can happen if you've already authorized the app once before. The oauth2 server will only ever mint one refresh token at a time, and if you request another access token via the flow it will operate as if you only asked for an access token.

Try going though [Manage third-party apps & services with access to your account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3466521?hl=en) revoke the access directly through google then try authorizing the app again.  You should then have a refresh token for the user.  Which will allow your script to request a new access token whenever it needs one.

If that doesn't work you can try constructing the flow object with prompt='consent' and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried your solution but it seems not working.. I'v also tried on my raspberry and I've discovered that, with the same files, it works, while my opensuse pc doesn't

Comment: Are you sure you created credentials of type other on google developer console? https://youtu.be/qwqJcyLQSSQ

Comment: Yeah. I've been through that process half a dozen times now. Still fails. The thing that's interesting is that I've followed things down in the debugger and the HTTP request it eventually makes doesn't have a basic Authorization header at all. I tried hacking in a matching Basic Auth header (using the debugger) and I still get the error. It's really frustrating.